# Security-Transparent Code

Tags: security, .net-4.0, transparency

can someone please explain to me what exactly Transparent Code is in scope of .net 4.0? What's the difference between transparent code, Security-Safe-Critical code and Security-Critical code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has created alot of documentation about this subject on MSDN:

Security changes in .Net 4.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103.aspx

Summary of security changes in .Net 4.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527276.aspx

Security transparent code level 2 (level 2 => from .Net 4.0)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102.aspx

Hope that this information will guide you into the right direction.